# ; Missing Error after Packing Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, packer

After using Packer (http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) I end up throwing a 
missing ; after (the long packer string). I have no idea of the what and why.
possible fix and explanation please?

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
ImageRotate:function(parameters)
{   
    if (this.Wilq32&&this.Wilq32.PhotoEffect) return;
    return (new Wilq32.PhotoEffect(this.get(0),parameters))._temp;
},
rotate:function(parameters)
{
    if (this.length===0) return;
    if (typeof parameters=="undefined") return;
    if (typeof parameters=="number") parameters={angle:parameters};
    var returned=[];
    for (var i=0,i0=this.length;i<i0;i++)
    {
        var element=this.get(i);    
        if (typeof element.Wilq32 == "undefined") 
            returned.push($($(element).ImageRotate(parameters)));
        else 
        {
            element.Wilq32.PhotoEffect._rotate(parameters.angle);
        }
    }
    return returned;
},

rotateAnimation:function(parameters)
{
    if (this.length===0) return;
    if (typeof parameters=="undefined") return;
    if (typeof parameters=="number") parameters={angle:parameters};
    var returned=[];
    for (var i=0,i0=this.length;i<i0;i++)
    {   
        var element=this.get(i);
        if (typeof element.Wilq32 == "undefined") 
            returned.push($($(element).ImageRotate(parameters)));
        else 
        {
            element.Wilq32.PhotoEffect._parameters.animateAngle = parameters.angle;
            element.Wilq32.PhotoEffect._parameters.callback = parameters.callback ||
            function()
            {
            };
            element.Wilq32.PhotoEffect._animateStart();
        }
    }
    return returned;
}

});

Wilq32={};

Wilq32.PhotoEffect=function(img,parameters)
{
            this._IEfix=img;
            this._parameters=parameters;
            this._parameters.className=img.className;
            this._parameters.id=img.getAttribute('id');

            if (!parameters) this._parameters={};
            this._angle=0;
            if (!parameters.angle) this._parameters.angle=0;
            this._temp=document.createElement('span');
            this._temp.Wilq32 = 
                {
                    PhotoEffect: this
                };          
            var image=img.src;
            img.parentNode.insertBefore(this._temp,img);
            this._img= new Image();
            this._img.src=image;
            this._img._ref=this;
            jQuery(this._img).bind("load", function()
            {
                this._ref._Loader.call(this._ref);
            });
            if (jQuery.browser.msie) if (this._img.complete) this._Loader();
}

Wilq32.PhotoEffect.prototype._Loader=
(function()
{
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)
    return function()
    {
        var src=this._IEfix.src;
        this._IEfix.parentNode.removeChild(this._IEfix);
        this._temp.setAttribute('id',this._parameters.id);
        this._temp.className=this._parameters.className;
        var width=this._img.width;
        var height=this._img.height;

        this._img._widthMax=this._img._heightMax=Math.sqrt((height)*(height) + (width) * (width));
        this._img._heightMax=Math.sqrt((height)*(height) + (width) * (width));

        this._vimage = document.createElement('v:image');
        this._vimage._ref=this;
        this._vimage.style.height=height;
        this._vimage.style.width=width;
        this._vimage.style.position="relative";
        this._temp.style.display="inline-block";
        this._temp.style.width=this._temp.style.height=this._img._heightMax;
        this._vimage.src=src;
        this._vimage.rotate=0;
        this._temp.appendChild(this._vimage);

        var self = this;
        this._parameters.animateAngle=0;
        if (this._parameters.bind) 
        {
            for (var a in this._parameters.bind) if (this._parameters.bind.hasOwnProperty(a)) 
            for (var b in this._parameters.bind[a]) if (this._parameters.bind[a].hasOwnProperty(b)) 
            jQuery(this._temp).bind(b,this._parameters.bind[a][b]);
        }
        this._rotate(this._parameters.angle);       

    }
    else
    return function ()
    {
        this._IEfix.parentNode.removeChild(this._IEfix);
        this._temp.setAttribute('id',this._parameters.id);
        this._temp.className=this._parameters.className;
        var width=this._img.width;
        var height=this._img.height;

        this._img._widthMax=this._img._heightMax=Math.sqrt((height)*(height) + (width) * (width));

        this._canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
        this._canvas._ref=this;
        this._canvas.height=height;
        this._canvas.width=width;

        this._canvas.setAttribute('width',width);

        this._temp.appendChild(this._canvas);

        var self = this;
        this._parameters.animateAngle=0;
        if (this._parameters.bind) 
        {
            for (var a in this._parameters.bind) if (this._parameters.bind.hasOwnProperty(a)) 
            for (var b in this._parameters.bind[a]) if (this._parameters.bind[a].hasOwnProperty(b)) 
            jQuery(this._canvas).bind(b,this._parameters.bind[a][b]);
        }
        this._cnv=this._canvas.getContext('2d');
        this._rotate(this._parameters.angle);
    }

})();

Wilq32.PhotoEffect.prototype._animateStart=function()
{   
    if (this._timer) clearTimeout(this._timer);
    this._animate();
}
Wilq32.PhotoEffect.prototype._animate=function()
{   
    var temp=this._angle;
    if (typeof this._parameters.animateAngle!="undefined") this._angle-=(this._angle-this._parameters.animateAngle)*0.1;
    if (typeof this._parameters.minAngle!="undefined") if (this._angle<this._parameters.minAngle) this._angle=this._parameters.minAngle;
    if (typeof this._parameters.maxAngle!="undefined") if (this._angle>this._parameters.maxAngle) this._angle=this._parameters.maxAngle; 

    if (Math.round(this._angle * 100 - temp * 100) == 0 && this._timer) 
        {
            clearTimeout(this._timer);
            if (this._parameters.callback) 
                this._parameters.callback();
        }
        else 
        {
            this._rotate(this._angle);
            var self = this;
            this._timer = setTimeout(function()
            {
                self._animate.call(self);
            }, 10);
        }
}

Wilq32.PhotoEffect.prototype._rotate = (function()
{
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)
    return function(angle)
    {
        this._vimage.style.rotation=angle;
        var radians=angle*Math.PI/180;
        this._vimage.style.top=  (this._img._heightMax - this._img.height)/2- (this._vimage.offsetHeight-this._img.height)/2 +"px";
        this._vimage.style.left= (this._img._widthMax - this._img.width)/2- (this._vimage.offsetWidth-this._img.width)/2 +"px";
    }
    else
    return function(angle)

    {

        if (!this._img.width) return;
        if (typeof angle!="number") return;
        angle=(angle%360)* Math.PI / 180;
        var width=this._img.width;
        var height=this._img.height;
        var widthAdd = this._img._widthMax - width;
        var heightAdd = this._img._heightMax - height;
        this._canvas.width = width+widthAdd;
        this._canvas.height = height+heightAdd;
        this._cnv.save();
        this._cnv.translate(widthAdd/2,heightAdd/2);
        this._cnv.translate(width/2,height/2); 
        this._cnv.rotate(angle);
        this._cnv.translate(-width/2,-height/2);
        this._cnv.drawImage(this._img, 0, 0);
        this._cnv.restore();
    }


})();
```

Comment: You've mentioned Packer and Prototype in your question, then quoted a bunch of un-packed code using jQuery.

Comment: Well actually I think he is saying he is packing that javascript code, some of which involves setting up a prototype.

Comment: ^ Same as above, I'm packing the code and its breaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packer jams everything onto one line if I'm not mistaken so that any missing semicolons that would have been originally parsed OK turn into hard errors.

There are a few missing semicolons in your js for example

```
return function(angle)
{
    this._vimage.style.rotation=angle;
    var radians=angle*Math.PI/180;
    this._vimage.style.top=  (this._img._heightMax - this._img.height)/2- (this._vimage.offsetHeight-this._img.height)/2 +"px";
    this._vimage.style.left= (this._img._widthMax - this._img.width)/2- (this._vimage.offsetWidth-this._img.width)/2 +"px";
}
```

is missing a semicolon.  there are more.

Comment: Basically he's missing semicolons after every function definition added to `Wilq32.PhotoEffect.prototype`

Comment: It actually looks like THIS might be the culprit somehow? everything works on one line until here:
  }
 else
 return function ()
 {

Comment: Yes, that's the else from `Wilq32.PhotoEffect.prototype._Loader`. You should wrap the if part in curly brackets, and add a semicolon like so: `if (jQuery.browser.msie){return function(){...};}else ...`. You should really take a look at jslint or jshint (jshint reported this, and other problems...). Adding `{}` and `;` sometimes helps the javascript engine resolve unambiguity.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that was exactly what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice site which will tell you what is wrong with your javascript: http://jslint.com/

So paste your code there, click on the `JSLint` button and observe the errors and warnings you get. Once you fix them you may be confident that when packed your javascript will work.

Comment: I find it very strange there is no "all ow if statement without brackets '{'". Its very bad practice, but perfectly valid.

Comment: @ Justin Dearing, I agree with you it's valid, but once you forget some trailing `;` it will bite you. That's why following best practices and always using `{` brackets helps.

Comment: Returned error Error:

Problem at line 1 character 92: Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'.

jQuery.fn.extend({ImageRotate:function(parameters){if(this.Wilq32&&this.Wilq3...

Problem at line 1 character 92: Stopping. (100% scanned).

Implied global: jQuery 1